# How to change Swatch Image on click swatch options in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have configured several products so that their images change according to the color selection, however nothing works. I recently installed an extension to be able to modify the sku of my configurable products, I don't know if it has a thing to do with the problem

Comment: can you explain me?

Comment: when I click on another color, the image does not change

Comment: can you share me screenshot please

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Comment: give me screenshot of your admin attribute so I can check it.

Answer (score 0):

The image should change but default image remains displayed.

[image: screen]

Comment: share me admin screenshot as well.

Comment: Edit your question please instead of adding as answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: screnshot]

The image of my configurable product

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please go admin==> stores=>Attributes=> Products

and find your attribute and try to edit and do below from image

[image]

Hope It works!

Comment: I cleared the cache etc but still don't works :(

Comment: have you using any extention?

Comment: The URL of my website is: http://bachelardpierre.com/soluclef2/iguane-grand-modele.html  yes i'm using an extension to have dynamic SKU for my configurable products.

Comment: How can i share you admin? skype?